# TXR: how to pivot concatenated tables?

Tags: text-processing

I've got data that looks like this:

```
i,a,b,c
1,0.2,3.2,4.5
2,0.8,4.1,3.5
3,0.5,3.1,4.1
i,a,b,c,d
4,3.2,5.2,7.5,1.1
5,2.8,5.1,8.5,0.9
6,2.5,5.1,8.1,1.0
i,a,d
7,3.2,5.2
8,2.8,5.1
9,2.5,5.1
```

I want to process it with TXR to look like this:

```
i,key,val
1,a,0.2
1,b,3.2
1,c,4.5
2,a,0.8
2,b,4.1
2,c,3.5
3,a,0.5
3,b,3.1
3,c,4.1
4,a,3.2
4,b,5.2
4,c,7.1
4,d,1.1
5,a,2.8
5,b,5.1
5,c,8.5
5,d,0.9
6,a,2.5
6,b,5.1
6,c,8.1
6,d,1.0
7,a,3.2
7,b,5.2
8,a,2.8
8,b,5.1
9,a,2.5
9,b,5.1
```

My current incorrect TXR script is:

```
@(output)
i,key,val
@(end)
@(repeat)
i,@(coll)@{key /[^,]+/}@(end)
@  (collect :gap 0)
@{i /[0-9]+/},@(coll)@{value /[^,]+/}@(end)
@  (end)
@  (output)
@    (repeat)
@      (repeat)
@i,@key,@value
@      (end)
@    (end)
@  (end)
@(end)
```

It produces instead:

```
i,key,val
1,a,0.2
1,a,3.2
1,a,4.5
2,b,0.8
2,b,4.1
2,b,3.5
3,c,0.5
3,c,3.1
3,c,4.1
4,a,3.2
4,a,5.2
4,a,7.5
4,a,1.1
5,b,2.8
5,b,5.1
5,b,8.5
5,b,0.9
6,c,2.5
6,c,5.1
6,c,8.1
6,c,1.0
7,a,3.2
7,a,5.2
8,d,2.8
8,d,5.1
9,,2.5
9,,5.1
```

How can I achieve the desired output? Can I use `@(merge)` somehow, or do I need to drop down to lisp? I saw there was a `transpose` function that might be useful for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is almost there. The problem is that the values have to be associated with keys. To do this, we can take advantage of a feature that was added in TXR 144, released on June 29, 2016: the `:counter` keyword supported in `collect` and `coll`:

```
@(output)
i,key,val
@(end)
@(repeat)
i,@(coll)@{keylist /[^,]+/}@(end)
@  (collect :gap 0)
@{i /[0-9]+/},@(coll :counter c)@{value /[^,]+/}@(bind key @[keylist c])@(end)
@  (end)
@  (output)
@    (repeat)
@      (repeat)
@i,@key,@value
@      (end)
@    (end)
@  (end)
@(end)
```

The keys are collected into the `keylist` variable instead of `key`, and `key` is bound together with `value` by indexing into `keylist` with `c`. The counter `c` steps from 0 by default; a different starting value can be specified with `:counter (c expr)`.

But let's not do it in this clunky way. I mean, look at what we are doing: we are stepping this counter through `keys` repeatedly and just collecting lists of keys in parallel with the values. We can achieve exactly the same thing with a single `bind` outside of the inner `coll`, like this:

```
@(output)
i,key,val
@(end)
@(repeat)
i,@(coll)@{keylist /[^,]+/}@(end)
@  (collect :gap 0)
@{i /[0-9]+/},@(coll)@{value /[^,]+/}@(end)
@  (bind key keylist)
@  (end)
@  (output)
@    (repeat)
@      (repeat)
@i,@key,@value
@      (end)
@    (end)
@  (end)
@(end)
```

See? To get the `value` list for each row, we collect the values. The keys do not change from row to row, so to obtain each `key` list to pair with th `value`, we just bind it from `keylist`.

If all we want to do with this logic is to obtain the printed output, then we can just not collect the rows and output after each row. In other words, it's just an exercise in collecting the key names, and then dumping them together with the values for each row in the given section:

```
@(output)
i,key,val
@(end)
@(repeat)
i,@(coll)@{key /[^,]+/}@(end)
@  (repeat :gap 0)
@{i /[0-9]+/},@(coll)@{value /[^,]+/}@(end)
@    (output)
@      (repeat)
@i,@key,@value
@      (end)
@    (end)
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Arguably, this is a good task for Awk. Not necessarily that Unix one, mind you:

```
(awk (:set fs "," ofs ",")
     (:let keys)
     (:begin (prn 'i 'key 'val))
     ((equal [f 0] "i") (set keys (rest f))
                        (next))
     (f (each ((k keys)
               (v (rest f)))
          (prn [f 0] k v))))
```

Comment: Thanks, again! Very impressed by how effortlessly TXR handled this problem.